# TfsConfig Identity /change for workgroup accounts to domain accounts

Tags: migration, team-foundation-server, user-accounts

I have successfully migrated a TFS 2005 Workgroup server to a new Team Project Collection in TFS 2010.

I am trying to use the `TfsConfig Identity /change /fromdomain:WORKGROUPNAME /todomain:DOMAINNAME` command, but nothings is being changed. Is this even possible or will I have to fat-finger the SQL Database directly to get this mapping working?

Or is there another way to fix-up those non-domain account identities in the new TFS 2010 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to map the WORKGROUP accounts to newly created (temporary) domain accounts.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.